# What is the equivalent code for this Swift code?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Hi I'm trying to implement player with youtube UI features. I got a sample code in swift so I converted it into Objective-C But I'm unable to convert the bottom code lines. Can anyone convert this ?

```
let scale = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: (1 - 0.5 * scaleFactor), y: (1 - 0.5 * scaleFactor))
    let trasform = scale.concatenating(CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: -(self.player.bounds.width / 4 * scaleFactor), y: -(self.player.bounds.height / 4 * scaleFactor)))
    self.player.transform = trasform
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it is the following code, I haven't tested it, since I don't know the result.

```
CGAffineTransform *scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale((1 - 0.5 * scaleFactor), (1 - 0.5 * scaleFactor));
CGAffineTransform *scale2 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-(self.player.bounds.width / 4 * scaleFactor), -(self.player.bounds.height / 4 * scaleFactor));
// concat the 2 CGAffineTransforms. 
CGAffineTransform *transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, scale2);
self.player.transform = transform;
```